# Next.js build on Gitlab does not build image cache from public folder

Tags: gitlab, next.js, cicd

I am running a CI/CD pipeline on **Gitlab**.

I am building a **Next.js** app and zipping the `.next` directory and `package.json` as an artifact so I can upload to **AWS S3**.

Things are working as expected, except...

---

All of the files in the `public` directory are not included with the build.
When I build **locally**, the images are saved within `.next/cache/images` as expected/. On **Gitlab**, they are not.  There is only the `webpack` directory within the `cache` folder.

This is confirmed in the Gitlab job CLI output and the artifact being stored, as there is no `images` directory in the cache directory UI as described.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this was the fact that **the public folder is not actually stored initially in the `.next` directory when built**.  The images are stored there at runtime and cached.

I was unaware of this... and noticed it as I was developing thge Next.js app locally, and was confirmed in a random thread in a next.js issue thread I happened upon.

If anyone has reference to this in the docs, please share.  Perhaps I'm just misreading the docs, but I did not know I had to do this when preparing a zip for CI/CD deployment.